# Make a variable accessible in all test methods. PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

In my test class I want a variable to be accessible from any test method. I know this is possible by initializing it in `setUp` method or declaring in bootstrap file.

But the issue is that the value of variable is unknown until test starts. It gets generated during a test and then used by subsequent test methods.

Currently I use this value by declaring subsequent methods to depend on the method, which generates the value, and then  passing the value using `return` statement from method generating the value. But I don't think this is proper way as I have to add return statement just to make variable accessible elsewhere.

Is there any standard way to make variable accessible to every method which gets generated dynamically during test method execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:
1. Create a public class. 
2. Declare the variable as global. 
You can reuse the variable in any part of your application.

Comment: Can you please add code for declaring variables as global and using them. I tried it using `$GLOBALS` inside a class, not a function. It shows syntax error. There are few question on SO to declare inside a function, but I want them in a plain class, without any function.